# ¿Como obtener un campo (fecha) de Podio en php?

Tags: php

estoy trabajando en una integracion con Podio.
Tengo el siguiente inconveniente cuando intento obtener un campo fecha me devuelve vacio, pero si es algun otro campo si lo muestra.
Lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente:

```
$filters = array (
        144199776 => $_POST['txtDniColaborador'],
        144690189 => 'BPO PERÚ S.A.C.'
    );

$item = PodioItem::filter($app_id, array( 
        'filters' => $filters,
        'limit' => 1,
        'sort_by' => 'created_on',
        'sort_desc' => true
 ));

 if(count($item)>0){
    $field_id = 'fecha-ini-de-contrato'; //cuando lo cambio a un campo texto por ej. dni no hay ningun problema
    foreach ($item as $field){
       echo $field->fields[$field_id]->start_date;
     }
 }
```

¿Alguna idea? Gracias....

---

Gracias por responder, con respecto a lo que imprime $item es demasiado grande.
Pero el resultado de `var_dump($field->fields[$field_id])` devuelve lo siguiente:

```
object(PodioCalculationItemField)#56 (5) { ["__attributes":"PodioObject":private]=> array(6) { ["field_id"]=> int(145434830) ["type"]=> string(11) "calculation" ["external_id"]=> string(21) "fecha-ini-de-contrato" ["label"]=> string(24) "FECHA INICIO DE CONTRATO" ["values"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["start"]=> string(19) "2019-01-14 00:00:00" ["start_date_utc"]=> string(10) "2019-01-14" ["start_time_utc"]=> NULL ["start_time"]=> NULL ["start_utc"]=> string(10) "2019-01-14" ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2019-01-14" } } ["config"]=> array(3) { ["settings"]=> array(8) { ["script"]=> string(73) "new Date(@[Min of FECHA INICIO DE CONTRATO](out_min_144117099_144182046))" ["color"]=> string(6) "DCEBD8" ["expression"]=> NULL ["time"]=> string(8) "disabled" ["calendar"]=> bool(false) ["decimals"]=> NULL ["return_type"]=> string(4) "date" ["unit"]=> NULL } ["mapping"]=> NULL ["label"]=> string(24) "FECHA INICIO DE CONTRATO" } } ["__belongs_to":"PodioObject":private]=> NULL ["__properties":"PodioObject":private]=> array(7) { ["field_id"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(7) "integer" ["options"]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> bool(true) } } ["type"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["options"]=> array(0) { } } ["external_id"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["options"]=> array(0) { } } ["label"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["options"]=> array(0) { } } ["values"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(5) "array" ["options"]=> array(0) { } } ["config"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(4) "hash" ["options"]=> array(0) { } } ["status"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["options"]=> array(0) { } } } ["__relationships":"PodioObject":private]=> array(0) { } ["__id_column":protected]=> string(8) "field_id" }
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. ¿Podrías decirnos qué mostraría un `var_dump($item);`?

Comment: @A.Cedano  agregue el resultado en la pregunta...

Comment: Desde el móvil se me hace difícil analizar el `var_dump` , pero parece que lo que hay dentro son arrays, y tú intentas sacarlos como si fueran propiedades de objetos. El valor `start_date` que buscas se encuentra dentro de un array de seis elementos: `array(6) ...` debes hacer referencia a ese array y encontrar el valor haciendo algo como esto: `$refArray["start_date"]`, donde $refArray equivaldría al array de seis elementos uno de los cuales es `start_date` ...

Comment: Prueba por tanto de este modo: `echo $field->fields[$field_id]["start_date"];` Aunque no estoy seguro que funcione, el var_dump hace pensar que los valores están anidados dentro de otros objetos y/o arrays y desde el móvil no me resulta fácil determinar cuál sería el camino exacto para llegar al valor que quieres. Quizá si pones el resultado del var_dump identado se podría analizar mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Es importante que comprendas la estructura de tu objeto para poder saber cómo tienes que acceder a sus datos.

Si organizamos el resultado del `var_dump` se vería así:

```
object(PodioCalculationItemField) #56 (5) 
{ 
    ["__attributes":"PodioObject":private]= > array(6) 
        {
            ["field_id"] => int(145434830)
            ["type"] => string(11) "calculation" 
            ["external_id"] => string(21) "fecha-ini-de-contrato" 
            ["label"] => string(24) "FECHA INICIO DE CONTRATO" 
            ["values"] => array(1) 
                {
                    [0] => array(6) 
                        {
                            ["start"] => string(19) "2019-01-14 00:00:00" 
                            ["start_date_utc"] => string(10) "2019-01-14" 
                            ["start_time_utc"] => NULL
                            ["start_time"] => NULL
                            ["start_utc"] => string(10) "2019-01-14" 
                            ["start_date"] => string(10) "2019-01-14"
                        }
                }
            ["config"] => array(3) 
                {
                    ["settings"] => array(8) 
                        {
                            ["script"] => string(73) "new Date(@[Min of FECHA INICIO DE CONTRATO](out_min_144117099_144182046))" 
                            ["color"] => string(6) "DCEBD8" 
                            ["expression"] => NULL
                            ["time"] => string(8) "disabled" 
                            ["calendar"] => bool(false)
                            ["decimals"] => NULL
                            ["return_type"] => string(4) "date" 
                            ["unit"] => NULL
                        }
                    ["mapping"] => NULL
                    ["label"] => string(24) "FECHA INICIO DE CONTRATO"
                }
    
        }


    ["__belongs_to": "PodioObject": private] => NULL
    ["__properties": "PodioObject": private] => array(7) 
        {
            ["field_id"] => array(2) 
                {
                    ["type"] => string(7)  "integer" 
                    ["options"] => array(1) 
                        {
                            ["id"] => bool(true)
                        }
                }
            ["type"] => array(2) 
                {
                    ["type"] => string(6) "string" 
                    ["options"] => array(0) 
                        {
                            
                        }
                }
            ["external_id"] => array(2) 
                {
                    ["type"] => string(6) "string" 
                    ["options"] => array(0) 
                        {
                            
                        }
                }
            ["label"] => array(2) 
                {
                    ["type"] => string(6) "string" 
                    ["options"] => array(0) 
                        {
                                
                        }
                }
            ["values"] => array(2) 
                {
                    ["type"] => string(5) "array" 
                    ["options"] => array(0) 
                        {
                                    
                        }
                }
            ["config"] => array(2) 
                {
                    ["type"] => string(4) "hash" 
                    ["options"] => array(0) 
                        {
                                    
                        }
                }
            ["status"] => array(2) 
                {
                    ["type"] => string(6) "string" 
                    ["options"] => array(0) 
                        {
                                    
                        }
                }
        }
        ["__relationships": "PodioObject": private] => array(0) 
            {
                
            }
        ["__id_column": protected] => string(8) "field_id"
}
```

En tu código se ve que quieres acceder al valor de `start_date` de esta manera:

```
 echo $field->fields[$field_id]->start_date;
```

Pero en el objeto ese valor se encuentra en otra parte. Vamos a analizar el contenido para que veas dónde está el valor:

La primera propiedad que aparece se llama `__attributes`

```
    ["__attributes":"PodioObject":private]= > array(6)
```

Y dice que esa propiedad tiene un array de seis elementos: `array(6)` ...

Los seis elementos de ese array son los siguientes:

- `filed_id`
- `type`
- `external_id`
- `laber`
- `values`
- `config`

Hay más propiedades y arrays anidados en el contenido del objeto, eso no nos interesa por ahora.

Vamos a detenernos en el índice llamado `values` del array de 6 elementos, porque es allí donde se encuentra el valor de `start_date` que tú quieres mostrar.

Este es el contenido de `values`:

```
        ["values"] => array(1) 
            {
                [0] => array(6) 
                    {
                        ["start"] => string(19) "2019-01-14 00:00:00" 
                        ["start_date_utc"] => string(10) "2019-01-14" 
                        ["start_time_utc"] => NULL
                        ["start_time"] => NULL
                        ["start_utc"] => string(10) "2019-01-14" 
                        ["start_date"] => string(10) "2019-01-14"
                    }
            }
```

Es un array de un elemento `array(1)`  y ese elemento es a su vez un array de seis elementos `array(6)`  y **uno de esos seis elementos es el que contiene el valor que buscas que es este**:

```
                        ["start_date"] => string(10) "2019-01-14"
```

---

### ¿Por qué tu código no funciona?

- Primero, porque no estás accediendo al lugar correcto donde se encuentra el valor.
- Segundo, porque estás accediendo a la clave del valor, como si fuera una propiedad de un objeto, cuando es una clave de un array. La sintaxis no es la misma, si es un objeto se accede así: `$objeto->propiedad`, si es una array se accede así: `$array["indice"]`.
- Tercero, intentas buscar algún valor en la clave `fecha-ini-de-contrato`. No sé por qué ni puedo decírtelo porque no conozco tu contexto. Pero si analizar el objeto (viendo el resultado del `var_dump` más arriba), verás que esa clave no tiene ninguna información relevante:  `["external_id"] => string(21) "fecha-ini-de-contrato"`

Si lo que realmente te interesa es `start_date`, o sea el valor `2019-01-14` en este caso, la forma correcta de acceder, como hemos dicho, sería esta:

```
$objeto["values"][0]["star_date"];
```

O, viendo que intentas mostrar el valor dentro de un bucle:

```
foreach ($item["values"] as $field)
{
       echo $field["start_date"];
}
```

Pero para que esto funcione, `$item` debe apuntar al lugar correcto dentro del objeto.

Comment: Gracias por responder ... 
Con respecto al `$field_id = 'fecha-ini-contrato'` es el campo de la tabla de Podio, es decir es necesario especificarlo.

Intente hacer algo como esto pero no retorna nada:
 `foreach($item as $field){ 
     echo $field->fields[$field_id]["start_date"];
  }`

Comment: @CarolinaPC tienes que analizar el objeto que se está creando. Se ve claramente que no hay ningún valor identificado por ese campo.

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguien le pasa igual, lo solucione de la siguiente forma:

El campo es tipo calculation pero se habia guardado una fecha y estaba haciendo conflicto con la misma librería de Podio.

**Ruta: models/PodioItemField.php (Línea 1122)**

```
public function __get($name) {
   $attribute = parent::__get($name);
    if ($name == 'values' && $attribute) {
     if(is_string($attribute[0]['value'])){
      return $attribute[0]['value'];
     }else{
      return $attribute[0]['start_date'];
     } 
    }
   return $attribute;
}
```

Ahora solo para obtener el valor se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
$filters = array (
        144199776 => $_POST['txtDniColaborador'],
        144690189 => 'BPO PERÚ S.A.C.'
    );

$item = PodioItem::filter($app_id, array( 
        'filters' => $filters,
        'limit' => 1,
        'sort_by' => 'created_on',
        'sort_desc' => true
 ));

 if(count($item)>0){
    $field_id = 'fecha-ini-de-contrato'; 
    foreach ($item as $field){
       echo $field->fields[$field_id]->values; //Aquí esta el cambio
     }
 }
```